# Cypress can't identify attributes of a Chakra UI element

Tags: automated-tests, attributes, cypress, gui-testing

I'm trying to use Cypress to test that a Chakra UI Heading element has the correct text and styling. I'm getting a passing test when I assert what the text should be, but I can't seem to get Cypress to identify the attributes of the element. Here is the Chakra UI element:

```
<Heading data-test="signup-header" as="h1" size="lg">Sign Up</Heading>
```

And here is my Cypress test:

```
describe("Sign Up flow", () => {
  it("Tests the sign up feature", () => {
    // Verifies page location
    cy.visit("/signup");
    cy.getDataTest("signup-header")
      .should("have.text", "Sign Up")
      .should("have.attr", "as");
  });
});
```

When I run the test, the text assertion passes, but the attribute assertion returns the following error:

```
AssertionError: Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '<h1.chakra-heading.css-1jb3vzl>' to have attribute 'as'
    at Context.eval (webpack://interviewguru/./cypress/e2e/signup.cy.js:7:7)
```

I also tried writing the test like this but was met with the same error:

```
describe("Sign Up flow", () => {
  it("Tests the sign up feature", () => {
    // Verifies page location
    cy.visit("/signup");
    cy.getDataTest("signup-header")
      .should("have.text", "Sign Up")
      .invoke("attr", "as")
      .should("eq", "h1");
  });
});
```

Any insights would be greatly appreciated! I'm new to automation testing and a bit stumped.

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet is source code,

```html
<Heading data-test="signup-header" as="h1" size="lg">Sign Up</Heading>
```

but in the running page the DOM will look something like the following

```html
<h1 class="chakra-heading css-r3x9fh" data-test="signup-header">Sign Up</h1>
```

because the `as="h1"` attribute is a compile-time instruction to output a `<h1>` element for this heading.

---

You can play with the code on this page [Heading - change visual size](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/heading/usage#changing-visual-size) to see what is compiled, by looking in the dev console.

[image]

---

Cypress can only work with the compiled version of the element, which means you would want to test the effect of the compilation process (i.e that the [tagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) property is correct)

```js
cy.getDataTest('signup-header')
  .should('have.text', 'Sign Up')
  .and('have.prop', 'tagName', 'H1')  // tagName is always capitalized
```